# How can I make PrimeFaces autocomplete has a fixed width with text wrapped?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces autocomplete which I believe is based on jQuery ui autocomplete is behaving strange with long texts the box with the results positions itself in a non visible area. This happens when the box width is greater than the available width resolution. It seems that the width of the container initialize itself with the width of the largest element found in the first search then the subsequent results are showed with the same width even though the elements of the result might be smaller in lenght. I would like the container to have a fixed width and that the text is wrapped instead of showing a horizontal scrollbar. I'm not sure if this is a bug, it seems to me because when there is no width available you cannot see anymore the results because is hidden on the left size of the screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Refresh the browser to reset the width of the container (F5):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Refresh the browser to reset the width of the container (F5), as you will see in these images part of the container is not visible and is hidden in the left side.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:oms="http://aom.org/oms"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="quotationForm" prependId="false">   
        <p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{autoCompleteBean.txt1}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.complete}"/>  
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

AutoCompleteBean.java:

```
package org.aom.oms.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;

@Model
public class AutoCompleteBean {  

    private String txt1;

    private List<String> texts = 
            Arrays.asList("a0", "b0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789","c012",
                    "c0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456");

    public List<String> complete(String query) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String text : texts) {
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                results.add(text);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String getTxt1() {  
        return txt1;  
    }  

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {  
        this.txt1 = txt1;  
    }  

}
```

PrimeFaces 3.4.2

Comment: Have you tried the styling (css) attributes for the component? They should be listed in the user guide: http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf